# How can I use ES6 modules on python http.server?

Tags: javascript, python, server

I'm instantiating a module like so in `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello Module</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`index.js` is empty.

When I serve this via `py -3 -m http.server` (Python 3.8.5), I get the Chrome error:

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I've read what this error signifies. I do not know how to configure http.server because heretorfore it's been a black box to me. Am I past the point at which Python's default (?) server is helpful?

Comment: Please show us the server code too.

Comment: See [issue35403](https://bugs.python.org/issue35403) on the Python issue tracker - you may need to use Python 3.8 as per the resolution.

Comment: @AKX That's my point of confusion; I don't know where or what http.server's code is.

Comment: No, please show the code where you use `http.server`.

Comment: @AKX Okay, my question is more thorough now.

Comment: Same error with node-static, so I'm missing something massive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JavaScript should be served with the content-type `text/javascript`.

[The default `http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` handler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ba18c0b13ba3c08077ea3db6658328523823a33f/Lib/http/server.py#L642-L647) may not (since mappings can be read from the Windows registry) have a mapping for the `.js` extension to a file type, or it might be wrong (as evident from `text/plain`).

You'll need to write your own short script to patch in the `.js` extension, and use that instead of `python -m http.server`, something like:

```
import http.server

HandlerClass = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

# Patch in the correct extensions
HandlerClass.extensions_map['.js'] = 'text/javascript'
HandlerClass.extensions_map['.mjs'] = 'text/javascript'

# Run the server (like `python -m http.server` does)
http.server.test(HandlerClass, port=8000)
```

Comment: I fixed the Windows registry value and that did the trick [with the default `http.server`].

Comment: This only worked for me as `application/javascript` not `text/javascript`

Comment: I seemed to have a cache issue where I was still getting the MIME type error even after starting this server. And then the error went away. So if this isn't working for anyone, you might want to disable cache in the dev tools.

Comment: I have still this error. Instead of `"text/plain"`, I have `"text/html"` as the type in the error message.

Comment: Strange: if I put this code in a script, and run either `python3 pyserver.py` or `python3 -m pyserver.py`, I get `Serving HTTP on :: port 8000 (http://[::]:8000/) ...` (same as `python3 -m http.server`), but trying to `wget -O- 127.0.0.1:8000` just hangs on "Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8000..." - while `python3 -m http.server` in the same terminal works?!