# Javascript Modules not working on some clients

Tags: javascript, windows, module, brave

I recently started using Javascript modules in my websites, and everything was fine when developing on my desktop. I went to do work on my laptop, but for some reason JS is throwing the following error:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but
> the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME
> type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Both of my machines are on the latest version of Windows 10 and Brave browser. Google doesn't have anything, and I am out of ideas. My best guess is some weird browser version issue, but I cant find anything about it.

Comment: The problem is with your  server configuration. That's where the broken MIME type is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
This is an issue with the http server I was using. My version of Python's http server on my laptop doesnt support modules. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166774/how-can-i-use-es6-modules-on-python-http-server) fixed my issue.
Also why do I have to wait 2 days to mark this as an answer?