# Working around missing ES6 functions in JavaScript import of libraries from CDN?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, cytoscape.js

I do not have much experience with Node.js, and when I try a JavaScript library, I try to write a single `test.html` file, that loads requirements for the library from an online CDN, and then develop my script there.

So, I tried to make that kind of an example for the demo shown on https://pathwaycommons.github.io/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet/. This is how far I got:

`test.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- based on https://pathwaycommons.github.io/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet/index.html -->
<html>
  <head>
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <title>test_cyto demo</title>

  <!--<script src="https://unpkg.com/whatwg-fetch@2.0.3/fetch.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>-->

  <style>
    body {
      font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    #cy2 {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 999;
    }

    h1 {
      opacity: 0.5;
      font-size: 1em;
      font-weight: bold;
            }
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <h1>test_cyto demo</h1>

  <div id="cy2">
  </div>

  <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash-es@4.17.21/lodash.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/whatwg-fetch@2.0.3/fetch.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="test_cyto_module.js" type="module"></script> <!-- needs a local server to serve this with correct MIME type for javascript; for python, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/63166774 -->
  </body>
</html>
```

`test_cyto_module.js`

```js
//~ import * as lodash_exports from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.js'; //  // seems to run, but no exports
//import * as lodash from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash-es@4.17.21/lodash.js'; //  // runs, with exports
//import * as lodash_exports from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash-es@4.17.21/lodash.js'; //  // runs, with exports
import { memoize } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash-es@4.17.21/lodash.js'; //  // runs, with exports
//~ Object.entries(lodash_exports).forEach(([name, exported]) => window[name] = exported); // runs after import * as demo_exports ...
//~ export { default as memoize } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash-es@4.17.21/lodash.js';
import * as demo_exports from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/PathwayCommons/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet@master/build/bundle.js'; // seems to run, but TypeError: memoize is not a function - even with lodash load above
//import * as demo_exports from 'https://pathwaycommons.github.io/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet/build/demo.js'; // object with only Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module", and it runs - to trick the running part, rename div id="cy" to div id="cy2 in html? that breaks cytoscape.min.js:32:157281 then .. 

function startup() {
  //import * as demo_exports from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/PathwayCommons/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet@master/build/bundle.js'; // import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
  console.log("startup lodash_exports ->", lodash_exports, "<-");
  console.log("startup demo_exports ->", demo_exports, "<-");
  Object.entries(demo_exports).forEach(([name, exported]) => console.log(name, exported));
  //Object.entries(ip6).forEach(([name, exported]) => console.log(name, exported));
}

export default { startup }

//startup(); // actually, this runs now; also as type="module"

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  startup();
}, false);
```

Basically, cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet has two files in its [build](https://github.com/PathwayCommons/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet/tree/master/build):

- [build/demo.js](https://pathwaycommons.github.io/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet/build/demo.js) - this does imports without errors, but contains the `demo.js` code (shown at end) that draws the demo on the "#cy" div, which I don't want; if I rename '#cy' to '#cy2' to avoid that, then something else crashes; and yet, I cannot find any functions like `sbgnStylesheet` being imported here
- [build/bundle.js](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/PathwayCommons/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet@master/build/bundle.js) - this import fails with "TypeError: memoize is not a function", even if I attempt to import memoize from lodash ...

So my question is: is there anything I can do, so I can use the cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet in my own/html JS pulled from CDN, and still be able to do my own version of the [demo.js](https://github.com/PathwayCommons/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet/blob/master/demo.js) they use:

```js
var sbgnStylesheet = require('./build/bundle.js');
var cytoscape = window.cytoscape;

var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  elements: fetch('./demo.json').then( res => res.json() ),
  layout: { name: 'preset' },
  style: sbgnStylesheet(cytoscape)
});
```

Comment: I added cytoscape.js as a tag - all the original tags seem  on the generic side for this question. Please edit or change tags if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it - the trick was, to try loading `lodash.js` (not `lodash-es.js`) via `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.js"></script>` in the HTML, and then hitting a breakpoint, inspecting `window`, and realising there is a `window._` property there related to `lodash`. Then one can add `window.memoize = window._.memoize ;` just before the import of `...cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet/build/bundle.js` - and there will be no more complaints of  "TypeError: memoize is not a function".

With that, here is the fixed code:

`test.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- based on https://pathwaycommons.github.io/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet/index.html -->
<html>
  <head>
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <title>test_cyto demo</title>

  <!--<script src="https://unpkg.com/whatwg-fetch@2.0.3/fetch.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>-->

  <style>
    body {
      font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    #cy {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 999;
    }

    h1 {
      opacity: 0.5;
      font-size: 1em;
      font-weight: bold;
            }
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <h1>test_cyto demo</h1>

  <div id="cy">
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash-es@4.17.21/lodash.js" type="module"></script> -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/whatwg-fetch@2.0.3/fetch.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="test_cyto_module.js" type="module"></script> <!-- needs a local server to serve this with correct MIME type for javascript; for python, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/63166774 -->
  </body>
</html>
```

`test_cyto_module.js`

```js
window.memoize = window._.memoize ; // expected from <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.js"></script> in html
import * as demo_exports from 'https://pathwaycommons.github.io/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet/build/bundle.js'; // now no more "TypeError: memoize is not a function"

function startup() {
  console.log("startup demo_exports ->", demo_exports, "<-");
  Object.entries(demo_exports).forEach(([name, exported]) => console.log(name, exported)); // not much here

  // at this point, we have window._: function lodash(value); window.memoize: function memoize(func, resolver); window.cytoscape: function Uu(e) - and window.cytoscapeSbgnStylesheet: function exports(cytoscape);
  // so, we can do:
  //var sbgnStylesheet = require('./build/bundle.js');
  var cytoscape = window.cytoscape;
  var sbgnStylesheet = window.cytoscapeSbgnStylesheet;

  var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    //elements: fetch('./demo.json').then( res => res.json() ),
    elements: fetch('https://pathwaycommons.github.io/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet/demo.json').then( res => res.json() ),
    layout: { name: 'preset' },
    style: sbgnStylesheet(cytoscape)
  });
}
```

... and then the example works ...